# Unity3D: Can't create primitives in for loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using a JSON formatted string to create some cubes in Unity. The idea is quite simple but it doesn't work.

```
public void CreateObject(string message)
{           

    Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray jsonArray = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Parse(message);          


    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.Count; i++)
    {                
        string jsonArrayString = jsonArray[i].ToString();   

        CompressorObject generator = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CompressorObject>(jsonArrayString);   

        GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        Debug.Log(i);    
    }

}
```

The problem is that no cubes are created. I tried to log i in order to determine when this whole operation dies, but it is only because of the line in which I try to create the cubes. The deserialization is working as intended. If I input a string which contains let's say 50 elements, the counter goes up to 49 (just as is should) - if I however leave the line

```
GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
```

in there, it never even reaches the log. I don't see any errors, there are no warning and I made sure that the whole process of creating an object like this is working. Any ideas why this may not work? Thanks!

Comment: Assuming this is at runtime? From the docs: "Note: `CreatePrimitive` may fail at runtime. This will happen if your project does not reference the following components: `MeshFilter`, `MeshRenderer`, and `BoxCollider` or `SphereCollider` at runtime. The recommended way to avoid this crash is to declare private properties of these types. The stripping system will recognise their use which include them in the build so will not delete these components."

I would assume it would throw an error through, not fail silently.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.CreatePrimitive.html

Comment: I'll look into it - just seems weird to me that `CreatePrimitive` works in any other script but not this one. And yes, I'd assume some kind of warning as well.

Comment: Have you tried it outside of the loop?

Comment: Yes, same problem. I also tried to use `Instantiate` with a prefab but to no avail. Both outside and inside the loop, it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Nothing showing in your inspector at runtime? Try set the position, something like: `GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube); cube.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);`

Comment: Already tried that. It works when I put it (even without setting a position) in the Start function, so the function itself does not seem to be the problem. I just can't get it to work inside the loop or even the whole function for that matter.

Comment: Where are you calling your `CreateObject ` function?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem eventually - I was calling the functions from a different thread, which I wasn't aware of. Apparently Unity allows functions such as `Instantiate` and `CreatePrimitive` only to be called from the main thread. That's something I'll have to work out but that explains the weird behavior I was getting.

Edit: I ended up using a tool called [UnityMainThreadDispatcher](https://github.com/PimDeWitte/UnityMainThreadDispatcher)  and now everything works like a charm!